# one select box with two functions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-selectbox

I'd like to know if it's possible for a select box to have two functions.

1.Redirects automatically when selecting an option using `value`.

2.Load content via ajax into the closest div using `data-file`.

```
<select class="loadurl">
 <option value="#">Select</option>
 <option value="contact.php">Contact</option>
 <option value="about.php">About</option>
 <option data-file="fans.php">Fans</option>
</select>
<div class="area"></div>
```

But when I tried the following script, the ajax option (Fans) didn't work but attempted to redirect instead. May I know how to have two functions in just one select box?  Here's a **[demo](http://painfulmouth.com/test/combineselectbox.php)**.

```
$(".loadurl").bind('change', function () {

  var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
  var loadfile =selected.data('file');
  var area = $(".area");

  $(this).next(".area").load(loadfile);
area.empty();

});


$('.loadurl').bind('change', function () {
    window.location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Redirecting to another page and loading content in next div. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The will fire both, want do want to achieve?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QLUL7/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a conditional choice here - if the selected option has `data-file` then load the target in the `area` else reload the page.

```
var area = $(".area");
$(".loadurl").on('change', function () {
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var loadfile = selected.data('file');
    if (loadfile) {
        area.empty();
        $(this).next('.area').load(loadfile);
    } else {
        window.location.href = $(this).val();
    }
});
```